# will upgrading ubuntu to 16.04 change my ruby version?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, updates, ruby

Will upgrading ubuntu version from 14.04 to 16 upgrade my ruby version 1.9.3 to its latest? I don't mind keeping multiple versions but it shouldn't delete the old one.

These are the upgrade steps I have taken down:

```
service apache2 stop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install update-manager-core
do-release-upgrade
lsb_release -a
service apache2 start
```

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 was the 2016-April release, so it's very old now.  The following shows the ruby packages available (in official repos) for each release (including 16.04) - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ruby

Comment: @guiverc Will it remove the old version ? Is there a way I can still keep it ? Should I skip sudo apt-get upgrade to get it that way ? Thanks

Comment: You could put a hold on the package (*so it cannot be upgraded*), however the *release-upgrader* will fail because it cannot upgrade that package, and I'd thus expect it to roll back the upgrade or fail.  If you need to continue using 14.04, Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is available (https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-14-04-esm-support)

Comment: Should I skip sudo apt-get upgrade to get it that way ? Thanks

Comment: `sudo apt upgrade` does not upgrade fully (it has limitations; `apt full-upgrade`) and won't *release-upgrade* anyway - refer https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html *though there are other methods of *release-upgrading* available for desktop releases.